# SpringBootでJSPが表示されない

Tags: java, spring-boot

SpringBootにて簡単なJSPを表示させようと思っているのですが、画面が表示されず。
404エラーが表示され色々やっているのですが一向に変わりません。
どなたかアドバイス頂けないでしょうか？
【手順】
１．STSのスタータープロジェクトで新規作成
２．pom.xmlに下記を追記

```
　　<dependency>
    　　<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    　　<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    　　<scope>provided</scope>
　　</dependency>
```

２．application.propertiesに下記を追記

```
　spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/ 
　spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

３．プロジェクトフォルダの直下にフォルダを作成

```
　src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views
```

４．上記viewsフォルダに「login.jsp」を配置。
login.jspの中身

```
　　<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    　　pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
　　<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
　　<html>
　　<head>
　　<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
　　<title>Hello, World! JPS</title>
　　</head>
　　  <body>
　　    <p>Hello, World! JSP</p>
　　  </body>
　　</html>
```

５．Controllerクラスを作成

```
@Controller
public class LoginAction {    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "login";
    }
```

６．STS上で実行して、ブラウザで下記のURLにアクセス。

```
 http://localhost:8081/
```

７．ブラウザには404エラーで表示され、JSPが表示されない。

```
**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jan 21 21:15:23 GMT+09:00 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

デバックモードで見ると、RequestMappingでメソッドは呼び出されていることは確認。
色々、試しているのですが一向に変わらず困っています。
何が設定が足りないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

質問文に記載している内容が正しいとすると、

```yml
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
```

の最後にスペースが入っていますので、これを削除する必要もあります。

[実行可能コードサンプル](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso73501) ([差分](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/e360276ef6f74f9d6a8f941b82ac89cf934d6712))

Comment: 「views/」の後ろのスペースに問題あることは分かったのですが
「.jsp」の前のスペースを削除しないと動きませんでした。
問題は解決しました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみに、自分の手元では問題なく動作したので本文では言及しませんでしたが、 `application.properties` ファイルの形式としては `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/` がより適切です(**イコール**が区切り文字)。 コロンを使うのは `application.yml` ファイルの形式です。[リファレンス(4.2.3節)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-files-importing)に実例があります。